# Displaying html conditionally and displaying only if a value is present

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```js
const displayPeople = people => {
  const html = people.map(
    person =>
      `<div class='person-item'>
    <h2 class='person-name'>${person.name}</h2>
    <p class='person-house'>${person.house}</p>
    </div>`
  );
  peopleGrid.innerHTML = html.join('');
};
```

However I only want to display the html content if the person has a house value. I no house then I don't want that person to be displayed.

Comment: What exactly constitutes a _"no house"_ condition? Is the `house` property present? `null`? `undefined`? Empty string?

Comment: you really ought to check out angular. It's specifically created to make this kind of thing simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the `people` array before mapping it to HTML to remove the *house-less* entries

```js
const html = people.filter(p => !!p.house).map(person => ...)
```

See [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use && operator with the left-hand condition

```
const displayPeople = people => {
  const html = people.map(
    person =>
      !!person.house && (
      `<div class='person-item'>
      <h2 class='person-name'>${person.name}</h2>
      <p class='person-house'>${person.house}</p>
      </div>`
    )
  );
  peopleGrid.innerHTML = html.join('');
};
```

Comment: Forget about it, if you use it in innerHTML better use @Phil solution

Comment: Was going to say, you might run into issues with stringifying `false`

Answer (score -1):

you can simply check => if (person.house) returns true, before creating the html. (person.house) will return true, if the person.house is not null or undefined.